# ExtJs 3.2.1 Unable to get property 'store' of undefined or null reference

Tags: extjs

Combo grid acting as a Multi select combo box displaying categories along with other single select combo boxes. These are left menus.

Main grid is displaying data on the right side including category. This is main data display.

I am trying to pre-select a row in combo grid when category matches the main grid check box selection.

I am able to get the rowIndex of the selected category in combo grid. But when I try to select row, I am getting "Unable to get property 'store' of undefined or null reference" error.
This line throws error:

> On Firefox, the error is: "TypeError: this.grid is undefined".
>
> On IE, the error is : Unable to get property 'store' of undefined or null reference.
> The error line is :`g.getSelectionModel().selectRow(rowIndex)`;

```
var vmcbItemSelMod = new Ext.grid.CheckboxSelectionModel({ // Main grid checkbox selection model
    singleSelect: true,
    header: "",
    checkOnly: true,
    listeners: {
        rowselect: function(sm, rIdx, rec) {
            var g = Ext.getCmp("ComboGrid"); // combo grid using as multi select.
            var hasSelections = g.getSelectionModel().hasSelection();
            if (hasSelections === true) {
                g.getSelectionModel().clearSelections();
            }
            g.store.load({
                params: {
                    action: "getValue",
                    id: id
                },
                callback: function(records, operation, success) {
                    var rowIndex = this.findExact('category', rec.get('category')); ==
                    >
                    g.getSelectionModel().selectRow(rowIndex);
                }
            });
        },
        rowdeselect: function(sm, rIdx, rec) {}
    }
});
```

Comment: Put var g = Ext.getCmp("ComboGrid"); again before g.getSelectionModel().selectRow(rowIndex); and se if works

Comment: I tried added var g = Ext.getCmp("ComboGrid"); again before g.getSelectionModel().selectRow(rowIndex); But it did not work. This error is not occurring when I open the Combo grid and then check the main grid check box. Its throwing error when combo grid not accessed previously.

Comment: It appears that the grid is only created when the dropdown is active, can you show it how you create the combobox and the dropdown?